# SQL alphanumerical sorting with non specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, columnsorting

I got to sort strings that do not share the same format and I got trouble finding a solution for this one. Tried several options on stackoverflow for this but it does not work for me because they are for specific formatted data.

Here are an example of data i must sort.

```
12-ABC
1-ABC
ABC-10
ABC-11
ABC-100
2-ABCD
ABC-100A
```

I got results like this with ORDER BY

```
1-ABC
12-ABC
2-ABCD
ABC-10
ABC-100
ABC-100A
ABC-11
```

But i would like to have this

```
1-ABC
2-ABCD
12-ABC
ABC-10
ABC-11
ABC-100
ABC-100A
```

How would you do it?

Comment: What you want isn't alphanumerical sorting. Sorting know nothing about formats. What is the logic behind this anyway? One can't even say that you sort based on one or the other "field". Whatever the logic is, I suspect it will be a *lot* easier if you split this multi-value field into separate fields with the correct types and write a simple `ORDER BY`. Even that `100A` looks like it wants to be two different fields. You probably need 2 text fields (Description, Flag) and 1 numeric (ID). `ORDER BY ID, Description, Flag` would work

Comment: I would start with writing down exact sorting rules, like: 1) numerics come before alphas 2) if value starts with numeric, sort first by its numeric value - etc etc. This way you find out, how to analyze column value, how to split it into sortable parts, in what order and how to sort parts end so on. After that it is only writing code, no trial and error required :)

Comment: What if you also have `3A-ABC` and `ABC-11A`? Also what if a value doesn't have a dash (like `30A` or `ACB`), is an empty string, or NULL? Can you include in your sample data and desired results how you want all these other edge cases handled (or declare which ones are not possible, like NOT NULL constraints, or check constraints on length or that the value contains a dash)?

Comment: Just to throw a huge wrench in, what about a value like '`17A12-AB1N9'`?

Comment: Just to add to the above, would you count sets of numeric characters separated by alphas as separate numbers for the sorting, or as one large number? Would you sort by each number followed by a letters group in turn, or all numbers then all letters. If there is only one group of each type of character in each value, you could use some pattern matching to separate the numbers and letters and sort them individually perhaps.

Comment: Separate the value in three columns: type, numeric_value, string_value. Then sort by these three columns.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a complicated problem.  Parsing strings is something that SQL is not designed for in general, and SQL Server in particular.

You are trying to extract a number from two parts of a string and sort by that number.  Arrgg!  That really suggests that you are storing multiple types of information in a string -- things that would perhaps be better represented in separate columns.

That said, you can do what you want.  Here is one method that works on the data you supplied in the question:

```
select t.str
from (values ('1-ABC'),
             ('12-ABC'),
             ('2-ABCD'),
             ('ABC-10'),
             ('ABC-100'),
             ('ABC-100A'),
             ('ABC-11')
     ) t(str) cross apply
     (values (left(str, charindex('-', str + '-') - 1), stuff(str, 1, charindex('-', str), ''))
     ) v(part1, part2)
order by coalesce(try_convert(int, v.part1), 999999999),
         part1,
         try_convert(int, left(v.part2, patindex('%[^0-9]%', v.part2 + 'x') - 1)),
         part2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82c2f9f60b14ccbe4e8f8165af0044a0) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string into number and text (on the '-') and sort then by the num column.  Something like:

```sql
select iif((charindex('-', str) > 0), (cast(substring(str, 1, (charindex('-', str)-1)) as integer)), 9999) as num, str
from (
    select '1-ABC' as str union all
    select '2-ABC' as str  union all
    select '12-ABC' as str  union all
    select 'ABC' as str
) tbl
order by num, str
```

This way you will sort by the numerical value first and then by the string. Here I just add a really high number to the none number values so the it will be ordered last.

Answer (score 0):

Thx guys for all your infos. I manage to get the thing works almost perfectly with this particular case.

```
select distinct PCE_NAM,
    --FIRST SECTION OF THE STRING
    --REPLICATE to fill 0s before numerics
    (CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM) = 0 then PCE_NAM
        WHEN CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM) > 0 and 
            ISNUMERIC(LEFT(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM) -1)) = 1 and
            LEN(LEFT(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM) -1)) <= 8
            then REPLICATE('0', 8-LEN(LEFT(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM) -1))) + LEFT(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM) -1)
        ELSE LEFT(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM) -1)
    END) as FirstPart,
    --SECOND SECTION OF THE STRING
    (CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM) = 0 then ''
        WHEN CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM) > 0 and 
            ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM)+1, LEN(PCE_NAM))) = 1 and
            LEN(SUBSTRING(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM)+1, LEN(PCE_NAM))) <= 8
            then REPLICATE('0', 8-LEN(SUBSTRING(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM)+1, LEN(PCE_NAM)))) + SUBSTRING(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM)+1, LEN(PCE_NAM))
        ELSE SUBSTRING(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM)+1, LEN(PCE_NAM))
    END) as SecondPart,
    --GET THE NUMERICS ONLY FROM THE SECOND SECTION SO CAN SORT PROPERLY
    (CASE 
        WHEN LEN(LEFT(SUBSTRING(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM)+1, LEN(PCE_NAM)), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM)+1, LEN(PCE_NAM))))) <= 8
            then REPLICATE('0', 8-LEN(
            LEFT(SUBSTRING(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM)+1, LEN(PCE_NAM)), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM)+1, LEN(PCE_NAM)))))) + 
            LEFT(SUBSTRING(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM)+1, LEN(PCE_NAM)), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM)+1, LEN(PCE_NAM))))
        ELSE LEFT(SUBSTRING(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM)+1, LEN(PCE_NAM)), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(PCE_NAM, CHARINDEX('-', PCE_NAM)+1, LEN(PCE_NAM))))
    END) as SecondPartF
from PARTS
order by FirstPart, SecondPartF, SecondPart
```